# Node JS Sequelize is throwing error relation does not for raw query even though the table does exist

Tags: node.js, sequelize.js

I am building a Node JS application and using Sequelize for database queries. I am having a problem with running raw queries. This is my query.

```
let sql = 'SELECT "UserTeams"."team_id","UserTeams"."user_id"';
    sql = sql + ' FROM "UserTeams"';
    sql = sql + ' WHERE "UserTeams"."user_id"=:userId AND "UserTeams"."team_id" IN';
    sql = sql + ' (SELECT "GameTeams"."team_id" FROM "GameTeams" WHERE "GameTeams"."game_id"=:gameId)';
    sql = sql + ' LIMIT 1';

    let records = await database.sequelize.query(sql, {
      replacements: {
        userId: userId,
        gameId: gameId
      },
      type: QueryTypes.SELECT
    })
```

When I run the query, I am getting this error.

```
relation "UserTeams" does not exist
```

When I checked the database, the table is there. What is wrong with my code and how can I fix it?

The followings are the table in the database.

[image]

Comment: Many issues like this is because of exact table naming and case sensitivity. Can you show us a result of what tables you see in your database via screenshot or query results?

Comment: share database structure

Comment: I just updated the question to include the screenshots of the table. Please, have a look.

Comment: try with `SELECT * from "UserTeams"`

Comment: It does not work either. @MERN

Comment: first, please check the db configuration, the other db/server is selected?

Comment: or, try with SELECT * from "UserTeam"

Comment: It does not work either.

Comment: can you show the resulting `console.log(sql)` string?

Comment: It is giving me this, SELECT "UserTeams"."team_id","UserTeams"."user_id" FROM "UserTeams" WHERE "UserTeams"."user_id"=:userId AND "UserTeams"."team_id" IN (SELECT "GameTeams"."team_id" FROM "GameTeams"
 WHERE "GameTeams"."game_id"=:gameId) LIMIT 1

Comment: https://github.com/nkhs/node-sequelize/compare/stack-68836708?expand=1

Comment: i checked on my side, with my simple project, but, it is working

Comment: umm. That's strange.

Comment: you need try with simple query

Comment: try with `SELECT * from "public.UserTeams"`

Comment: It says, 'relation "public.UserTeams" does not exist',

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/236153/discussion-between-mern-and-wai-yan-hein).